# how to access global variables inside google autocomplete async callback?

Tags: angularjs, callback, leaflet, asynccallback, google-places-autocomplete

So I am working on an angular project where I am using leaflet-google-places-autocomplete API on top of leaflet framework.

My goal is to retrieve location data from the API and use it elsewhere in my component. But I am not able to get data out of the async callback function.
This is my API implementation:

```
placesLatLng: any; //global variable
initPlaces(){
    let gplaces = new L.control.GPlacesAutocomplete({
        position: 'topleft',
        callback: this.getLoc,
    });
    gplaces.addTo(this.map);
}

//async callback
getLoc(results){
    //result holds all the data I need
    this.placesLatLng = results.geometry.location; //I need to use this value elsewhere.
}
```

But when I try to do this, I get an error saying cannot read property this.placesLatLng of undefined. I have seen solutions where we need to use promises but haven't seen it is this particular situation.

Any help related to this issue will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer? i.e. that you want to initialize your global variable like this?

```
var any = 'some value'  // set value for global var

placesLatLng = any;     // initialize global var, 
                        // use '=' instead of ':'
```